# Python: Sum Of The Final Two Numbers In A List, Then Append

Tags: python, list, append, fibonacci

For example lets say my input is 12, I am attempting to get the output of the lucas sequence to be [2 1 3 4 7 11], but instead I keep receiving the output of
[2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199]. I'm attempting to get it to display the previous sequence number before my input, but I am struggling to find out.

This is my code

```html
my_list = [2, 1]
input = 12

while len(my_list) in range(input):
    for i in my_list:
        second_to_last = my_list[-2]
        counter = i + second_to_last
    my_list.append(counter)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: It's unclear what output you want.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The desired output is in the question.

Comment: `while len(my_list) in range(input):` means you want the final length to be 11. Why do you expect the result to be only 6 elements?

Comment: BTW, why use `range()`? Why not just `while len(my_list) < input:`?

Comment: Also, don't use `input` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: `second_to_last = my_list[-2]` doesn't need to be in the `for` loop, since it doesn't change depending on `i`.

Comment: `counter = sum(i + second_to_last for i in my_list)` or `counter = sum(my_list) + len(my_list) * second_to_last`

Comment: @Barmar Overly complicated. Just fill the list with `sum(my_list[-2:])`.

Comment: @Guimoute I was assuming his calculations were correct and the problem was just the condition. I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs while your list has less than 12 elements but your desired output implies that it should run while the last element is less than 12.

If you want to specify a maximal length, do this:

```
my_list = [2, 1]
max_length = 12

while len(my_list) < max_length:
    my_list.append(sum(my_list[-2:]))

print(my_list)
# [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199]
```

If you want a maximal last value, do that:

```
my_list = [2, 1]
max_last = 12

while my_list[-1] < max_last :
     my_list.append(sum(my_list[-2:]))
my_list.pop(-1)

print(my_list)
# [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `for` loop. You just need to add the last two elements, not all the elements.

And you want to stop if the new element to be added exceeds the limit, so add that check into the loop.

```
my_list = [2, 1]
limit = 12

while True:
    next_element = my_list[-1] + my_list[-2]
    if next_element >= limit:
        break
    my_list.append(next_element)

print(my_list)
```